# Does LaunchDarkly's SDK rely on the local feature store or the streaming API, when clients ask for a toggle value?

Tags: toggle, feature-selection

Am looking at using LauchDarkly's (LD) java sdk to consume toggles from LD. From when I have read, I understand that it uses streaming API, which means when toggle values are changed in LD (via Dashboard) those changes are pushed to all the LD clients that are connected. When I looked at the source code for the SDK, i noticed that it uses a local cache (Feature Store) to store all the flags.

My question is around, how does the SDK fetch the toggle value? When clients ask the SDK for a toggle value, is the value looked up in the local feature store or does it actually make a call to the streaming api?

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed with Lauch Darkly's support. Here is what they had to say

"Once initialized, the SDK will evaluate the flag for a user against the store. The store is then updated via the streaming connection when there are flag changes."

K